# How to convert second order ODE into first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the second order ODEs:

\begin{align}
\frac{d^{2} x}{dt^2} &= - \frac{G M x}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}
\\
\frac{d^{2} y}{dt^2} &= - \frac{G M y}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align}

How can I convert these into first order ODEs? Any general guidance is appreciated. thanks

Comment: I would convert to polar coordinates first.

Comment: this is one-body-problem, in gravitional field. It can be solved @Andrei commented in polar coordinates, it can be integrated directly there

Answer (score 0):

Set $u = x'$ and $v = y'$ then
\begin{align}
u' &= - \frac{G M x}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}\\
v' &= - \frac{G M y}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}\\
x' &= u\\
y' &= v
\end{align}

Now we have a vector $z = (u,v,x,y)^T \in \mathbb R^4$ and a function $f:\mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^4$, namely $f(z) = (- \frac{G M x}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}\ ,- \frac{G M y}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}\ ,u,v)^T$ and the last equation can now be written as
$$
z'(t) = f(z)
$$
this is an autonomous equation.

Comment: do you know how I can solve this using solve_ivp with a numerical algorithm? I dont quite understand your expressions and how I can implement them

Comment: I don't know about numerical solutions, but I added sth, I hope it helps understanding the my answer